# Is there a good way to build a DIY LCD KVM?

Tags: rackspace, server-room, keyboard-video-mouse

I've wondered for some time whether it would be possible to build an LCD KVM. My server room has two KVM switches with CRTs, and I really don't want to shell out $1000+ on one of the nice 1U rackmount pull-out KVMs just for a bit more rack space. Is there any to use a laptop, or something similar to build a 1U rackmount KVM?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/111803/is-there-a-way-to-use-a-laptop-as-a-physical-console

Comment: Or how about, a rackmount bracket with the standard 75mm, and 100mm mount points.  http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/702894-REG/Delvcam_ULCD_1_ULCD_1_Adjustable_Depth_LCD.html

Comment: I saw that post, but I really don't care if it's a laptop. Thanks for the LCD monitor bracket link!

Comment: Dump the KMV idea and get iLO, ILOM, DRAC, or RSA. Much more flexible and zero KVM mess in-rack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a laptop and add a [Startech USB Crash Cart](http://www.startech.com/Server-Management/KVM-Switches/Portable-USB-PS-2-KVM-Console-Adapter-for-Notebook-PCs~NOTECONS01) to provide KVM functionality.

Answer (score 2):

By the time you pay for a laptop, a multi-port KVM and a drawer you're at least 3/4 of the way (if not 100%) to the cost of a ready-to-use unit.

Comment: My server room has all those already, I just want to put them together!

Comment: @zinspire: Then I don't understand your question. You just need a device like the one in the accepted answer to the question Zoredache linked to.